# How to insert Brazilian translation to MS SQL?

Tags: html, sql

I have a website that has multiple translations. Everything is working fine for Chinese, Japanese and other languages. For some reason when we add some Portuguese characters it replaces with ? marks.

Any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you are using a different encoding between your site and the database, It is recommended changing your encoding to UTF8 in the Html Headers, Meta encoding Tags and Database.

This is a good article about this topic.

[Handling Unicode Front to Back in a Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Thanks... I just noticed that is an issue with IE